# SQLite header and source version mismatch

Tags: macos, sqlite

Just installed SQlite3 with homebrew, but when I go to run it I get the following:

```
SQLite header and source version mismatch
2011-06-25 16:35:41 8f8b373eed7052e6e93c1805fc1effcf1db09366
2012-01-16 13:28:40 ebd01a8deffb5024a5d7494eef800d2366d97204
```

Noticed that people on Linux and Ubuntu have this problem sometimes, but I'm on a Mac (OS X 10.7.5) so the same solves for them didn't work through Terminal.

Assume there must be another version installed somewhere, but not sure how to solve the problem (fairly new, so over explain please).

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm having this same problem right now. I'll let you know if I figure anything out but it seems to be a real pain in the ass so far. I'm on ubuntu and none of the terminal commands are working...

Comment: I just solved it on my end: I copied the sqlite3 exec file that was in my /usr/bin and then replaced the sqlite3 exec in my /usr/local/bin with it. Now it works fine. So far...

Answer (score 6):

I left an answer in the comments but wanted to officially answer on what worked for me:

1. I copied the sqlite3 exec file that was in my /usr/bin
2. I replaced the sqlite3 exec in my /usr/local/bin with the copy I made from my /usr/bin

Now it works fine! (I also saved the old Sqlite3 exec file as .old incase I run into any bugs)

Comment: didn't work for me. In fact I didn't have any sqlite3 file in /usr/local/bin

Answer (score 1):

I think you once installed sqlite3 as dependency from another installation. This installation as executed by pkg-manager, will install sqlite3 into `/usr/bin/`.

And I assumed this time you wanted install sqlite3 from building its source. As you install sqlite3 manually, `./configure` script will assume your prefix be: `/usr/local/bin`.

So if you don't want this conflict, try:
`./configure --prefix=/usr/` to indicate you want to install into `/usr/bin/`, thus replace the older one.

regards

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, replacing `libsqlite3.so.0` and `libsqlite3.so.0.8.6` in `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu` by copying the version from `/usr/local/lib`, and overwriting the version in `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu` also solved the sqlite3 problem for me.

However, this then interferes with `Skype 4.2 for Linux` working, causing the message

> $ skype
>
> skype: error while loading shared libraries: libsqlite3.so.0: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64

Answer (score 0):

This is mostly happening because mismatch of sqlite3 client and other binaries. In my case

> IN-PF1CCNV7:/usr/lib64 # rpm -qa | grep sqlite                                                                                                                                                                                               sqlite3-3.28.0-lp151.2.3.1.x86_64                                                                                                                                                                                                            libsqlite3-0-3.23.1-1.10.x86_64                                                                                                                                                                                                              sqlite3-devel-3.23.1-lp150.1.1.x86_64                                                                                                                                                                                                        IN-PF1CCNV7:/usr/lib64 # zypper install sqlite3

I uninstalled sqlite3 and installed same rpm as sqlite3-devel

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me right now on Centos 7.

I solved moving binaries in /usr/lib64 and /usr/bin

```
mv /opt/usr/bin/sqlite3 /usr/lib64 
mv /opt/usr/bin/sqlite3 /usr/bin
```

headers in /usr/include

```
mv /opt/usr/include/sqlite3.h /usr/include/sqlite3.h 
mv /opt/usr/include/sqlite3ext.h /usr/include/sqlite3ext.h
```

and libraries in /usr/lib64

```
mv /opt/usr/bin/sqlite3 /usr/lib64/ 
cp /usr/lib64/ /usr/bin/
```